# Google LoggingAppender and stdout

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, logback, google-logging

For debugging/testing purposes, I would like Google's Logback LoggingAppender to write to STDOUT instead to connect to Google's Logging API. According to https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging-logback, this should be possible by using `redirectToStdout`.

My logback.xml:

```
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
        <redirectToStdout>true</redirectToStdout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
```

However, I get an error that no project was set. The error message:

```
14:48:36,515 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender]
14:48:36,534 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
14:48:36,970 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@28:16 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [appender] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.
    at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.
    at  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:142)
    ...
```

Although that should not be necessary according to the documentation cited above, I also tried setting `logDestinationProjectId`. Note, that doesn't make sense in my case, as I want to run this configuration on my local machine for debug/test purposes. Also, that produced a different error (although that should be ignored according to the documentation).

Any hints what I am missing? Is my use case even supported? If not, how do you test a configuration change for your LoggingAppender before deploying it to Google Cloud?

Comment: Created an issue for the maintainer, in case it is a real bug: https://github.com/googleapis/java-logging-logback/issues/930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked github issue was accepted and confirmed by a contributor. You can work around by setting an arbitrary project ID, i.e. by setting `logDestinationProjectId`:

```
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
        <redirectToStdout>true</redirectToStdout>
        <logDestinationProjectId>TEST</logDestinationProjectId>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
```